# why bash increment: `n=0;((n++));` return error?

Tags: bash, error-handling

```
n=0;
((n++));echo "ret=$?;n=$n;"
((n++));echo "ret=$?;n=$n;"
((n++));echo "ret=$?;n=$n;"
```

from `n=1` on, `((n++))` works correctly,
only when `n=0`, `((n++))` return error,
and I am using a `trap '' ERR` that is causing trouble with that

is it some bug?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Even if you've read the question it's is supposed to be a duplicate of, you still need the information that `((expr))` is equivalent to `let "expr"` to make the connection. This information is given in the answers to this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because the return value of `(( expression ))` is not used for error indication. From the `bash` manpage:

> ((*expression*))
>
> The *expression* is evaluated according to the rules described below under **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1. This is exactly equivalent to **let** "*expression*".

So, in your case, because the value of the expression **is** zero, the return status of `(( ... ))` is 1.

Comment: `((0))` and `((2-2))` all failed, thx!

Answer (score 14):

The reason is as pmos writes above.

One solution would be to use `((++n))` to do increment.  Your expression will never evaluate to zero, and so never look like it causes an error.

Comment: to avoid the trap, I did this `((n++))&&:`, but your answer works best, unless `n=-1`, as "most times" `n=0` it will work fine :)

Answer (score 4):

You should do:

```
echo "$((n+=1))"
```

It will not raise any traps - its only return comes from `echo`.

Or if you desire to use it as a standalone, in cases in which `$n` remains less than some 20 digits the following two forms always return true:

```
n=$((n+1))
```

Or :

```
: "$((n+=1))"
```

Comment: this also works every time `((n++))&&:`

Comment: @AquariusPower - eww. Why in the world would you call out to a nonportable function to increment a variable when you can portably increment same by just evaluating it in the first place?

Comment: my project is in bash :)

Comment: @AquariusPower - in my opinion, that doesnt give license for bad habits. It is far better to strive for portability where possible, and to adopt the saner convenience functions where necessary. `((n++))&&:` is not among the sane ones.

Comment: you mean that while using bash it may fail for someone else despite it is working here? because my scripts all enforce `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @AquariusPower - I mean that someone might someday want to adapt your work, and you shouldnt make it more difficult for no reason. Moreover, you would benefit overall from a more portability aware mindset - understanding how and why things interact on different platforms is a long step in the right direction toward understanding how and why they work at all. And last - have you tried benchmarking your project in a more streamlined shell such as `dash` vs. `bash`? My own tests usually point to 2:1 performance benefits when the script is well written.

Comment: mmm.. I have a script that the more performance it have, the best; I saw `((n++))` wont work in `dash`, I am thinking on recoding it and I think I will try it with `dash`, thx on the tip :); also I could find no free and good bash to c compillers..

Comment: @AquariusPower - I'm glad I could convince you. I should note that those *performance benefits* to which I refer can only ever be realized with regards to memory processing and function declaration/invocation. `dash` isn't likely to write out a file any quicker than will `bash`, but it will very likely loop over reading a file with better efficiency. And heredocuments are anonymous pipes in `dash` - they are not literal tmp files like `bash`.

Comment: I need to perform string parsing, translating tokens to escaped chars, very fast; hope it works

Comment: @AquariusPower - Oh, wow. *translating tokens to escaped chars* - you mean [like this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=16760899#16760899)? If you scroll further down to the conversation i had w/ derobert about it, youll see that the second to last line should now read `shift ; done ; echo`. Anyway, that single quotes an entire argument array - while `'\''` quoting any single quotes its arguments contain - in a single iteration per argument while relying only on shell builtins and POSIX code. Or maybe you mean `printf \\b\\b\\b\\n | od -An -v -tc -w1`?

Comment: @AquariusPower - actually, I can't swear to the portability of those `od` args, but this is portable: `printf \\b\\b\\b\\n |sed -n l`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15999/discussion-between-aquarius-power-and-mikeserv).